# How to get last element from NSMutableArray in which status as complete?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array of dictionaries in following format

```
[
{
 "status":"not completed",
 "rating":2 
},{
"status":"completed",
 "rating":2 
},{
"status":"not completed",
"rating":"<null>" 
},{
 "status":"completed",
 "rating":"<null>"},{
"status":"not completed",
"rating":"<null>" 
}
]
```

and from this i want response as last object where status is completed and rating is null

```
output
{
     "status":"completed",
     "rating":"<null>"
}
```

how do i get second element easily without any big iteration.

in real case this array might contains 150-300 elements.

```
  -(void)checkRecentUnratedOrder:(NSMutableArray *)order{

    NSLog(@"trip log - %@",[order valueForKey:@"status"]); // total 5 objects inside array in that 4 of them are completed

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.status == completed"];
    NSArray *arr = [order filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    NSLog(@"trip arr%@",arr);




}
```

console
[image]

Comment: Start at the end of the array and iterate backwards. As soon as you find an element with a "status" of "completed", return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `predicate` your array like this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.status == 'completed'"];
NSArray *arr = [order filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
// Now `arr` contains all the `dictionary` that `status` key contain `completed` value.
```

Comment: can i add multiple conditions in predicate?

Comment: Yes, using separator `and` / `or` on the basis of condition.

Comment: Yes you can add multiple conditions.

Comment: @Bangalore What other condition you want?

Comment: this is my code  where Order is NSDictionary  -----------------------  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.status == completed"];
    NSArray *arr = [[order valueForKey:@"status"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Comment: You need to use new filtered array `arr` like my answer.

Comment: My status field is [order valueforkey:"status"]   and order is NSMutableArray

Comment: Check my answer where i have use your `order` array change your code like that.

Comment: it showing empty array, even i have 4 completed one

Comment: Please put your whole code in question because you have something changed

Comment: If you create array like this `NSArray *arr = [[order valueForKey:@"status"]` then this array only contain value `completed` and `not completed` not the dictionary.

Comment: please check my question with console screenshot and code

Comment: check my edit, forgot to put `single quote` with completed please check it i have added `single quote`.

Comment: i need to check one more field "rating" whether its null or not

Comment: can you put the dictionary response and what you want from response?

Comment: rating format is like this rating = "<null>";  i need only status completed and rating <null> objects in array

Comment: Please add whole response of one dictionary from array that will be help full also check this <null> is string because it is coming with `double quote`.

Comment: Have you check <null> is string or something else.

Comment: yup it coming as "<null>"  in console

Comment: Not like that, check your last object of dictionary like this way `NSString *str = [arr lastObject] valueForKey:@"rating"]` and print value of `str`

Comment: printing as like this trip arr<null>

Comment: @Nirav its crashing when i try to use array without any complete status [order filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]